# Laravel eager loading issue

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eager-loading

Say I have an `orders` table and a `users` table and a `guests` table, for a company who accept orders from both `users` and `guests`.

I also have a `is_guest` boolean on the `orders` table which lets me know quickly whether the order has been made by a guest or a registered user.

I have a model method called `customer` which returns the eloquent relation like so:

```
public function customer()
{
  return $this->is_guest ? $this->belongsTo('Guest', 'user_id') : $this->belongsTo('User', 'user_id');
}
```

This works very well when I pass `orders` to the view and access the customer's data like so:

```
// Maps to either $order->user->firstname OR $order->guest->firstname
echo $order->customer->firstname;
```

But when I try to use this functionality when using eager loading it doesn't quite work:

```
$orders = Order::with('customer')->get();
return Response::make($orders);
```

It only returns the eager loaded customer data for **either the `user` or the `guest`** and never both.

I'm wondering why this is and how to get round it?

Is it because of the way the eager loading works - it only calls the `customer()` method *once* just as it only hits the database once, so whatever the first result of the query is, it will use that to determine the rest of the query too?

If I am trying to get a JSON response of all the `order` data *with* all of the customer's details too, how would I do that?

Thanks.

## UPDATE

Yes, turns out I was abusing the Laravel relationship method by adding a condition.
Using the polymorphic relations is a much better approach as suggested by @lukasgeiter.
http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#polymorphic-relations

I did have trouble loading other relations *based on the polymorphic relation*. For example if both `User` and `Guest` had corresponding tables `UserDetail` and `GuestDetail` then I couldn't get the eager loading to work. So I added this to both the `User` and `Guest` models:

```
protected $with = ['detail'];
```

This means that whenever the `customer` polymorphic relation is eager loaded, then both `User` and `Guest` will load their relationships automatically. I think I could have also used the 'lazy loading' functionality `$order->load('customer')` but I didn't try it out.

```
public function detail()
{
    return $this->hasOne('UserDetail');
}
```

Thanks guys.

Comment: It will use the result from the first time it's called on the page yes. I also think that using a condition in a relation is not quite what Taylor had in mind for it :P

Comment: You might want look into [polymorphism](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#polymorphic-relations) for this guest/user setup

Comment: Thanks for the info - yes I did think it was a bit of a hack but it worked so well in my views :)
Is this a common issue with database structure then? Should I instead have `orders_guests` and `orders_users` pivot tables?

Comment: Thanks @lukasgeiter - that does seem to be what I'm looking for. Hopefully I can get that working.

Comment: First of all, you need to parse Model name under `with` method not method name of the model. The model name would you want to eager loading with.